# Combined Android Project but Maps isn't working on my phone

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My partner and I are developing an android project on our own laptops. So we combine our work through GitHub(you probably knew that anyway). So my problem is after we have combined our project, the maps that she added in our app isn't working on my phone. We figured and saw the error/log message saying:

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key:
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):
```

I have tried changing the API according to what my Android Studio provided for the fingerprint. It didn't work also. Thus, I want to understand the logic behind this. ^^" So if anyone can kindly explain it to me, it will be much appreciated!

P.S.: and if possible to let me know how to fix it too. =)

Answer (score 0):

You have the new google maps key with another application certificate from each developer.

For more information read this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en-419#restrict-key)

Comment: Yes. I knew that already but please excuse me if I'm wrong, by google maps key did you mean; that it will be taken when we enable the API and then put the app certificate on the Google Service Online?